# Does Android's Vector Drawables support vector effects?

Tags: android, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

I'm wondering if [Android's Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) support [vector-effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke).

I'm attmepting to scale something but I'd like to preserve the stroke width by using `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

Comment: The link in the question would suggest not since it's not listed there.

Answer (score -1):

Vector-effects is available in SVG. All attributes of SVGs are not supported in VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable classes. Please refer to the documentation of the two classes in Android Developers site. If you use unsupported attributes / elements in .xml files then the app silently crashes.